# Making a guess a number game, but it won't print anything out

Tags: java

I was wandering, why this code doesn't print out anything?

```
package Main;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Counter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random rand = new Random();
        int numberOfTries = 0;
        int numberToGuess = rand.nextInt(1000);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int guess;
        boolean win = false;

        while (win = false) {
            System.out.println("Guess a number between 0 and 1000");
            guess = input.nextInt(50);
            numberOfTries++;
            {
                System.out.println("Number of Tries is " + numberOfTries);
            }

            if (guess == numberToGuess) {
                System.out.println("You win");
                win = true;
            } else if (guess < numberToGuess) {
                System.out.println("Number is higher");
            } else if (guess > numberToGuess) {
                System.out.println("Number is Lower");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: To make a comparison, you need to use `==` operator: `while (win == false) {...}`. `win = false` only assigns `false` to `win` and then evaluates to `false`. That's why the loop is never executed.

Comment: I just changed it as you said, and i understand why  (:
Though it still won't print anything

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the `while` statement, it should be `while (win == false)`. A single `=` acts as assignment operator and consequently return the same value of the assignment (false). The proper logical operator to test equality is `==`.

Comment: Please edit your answer and explain the difference between `=` and `==`.

Comment: I just changed it as you said, and i understand why  (:
Though it still won't print anything

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while (win = false) // this is not a logical operator
```

to

```
while (win == false) // this is
```

---

Also note you might be confusing

```
rand.nextInt(50); // generates a random number within the bound = 50
```

with

```
guess = input.nextInt(50); // expects the user input which should be of type int using radix 50
```

So you shall change this to

```
guess = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: I changed the == parts
Though it still won't print

I don't quite get what you mean by the rest, as it seems like its already the way i set it up (:

Comment: @HobieObarzanek please go through the updated answer

Comment: Even though i also change that part, nothing happens

Comment: @HobieObarzanek Please update the question with your modified code in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems. The `=` in `while (win = false) {` is the assignment operator, not the logical operator. Instead you should have

```
while (win == false) {
```

Second, the `nextInt` method in the `Scanner` class does not take an argument. Remove the `50` from `guess = input.nextInt(50);`

```
guess = input.nextInt();
```

I was able to run your program after those two modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but in where do you write your guess then? 
And even though i did remove it, it still won't print nothing

Comment: It depends how you're running your code. I put your program in Eclipse and was able to interact with it in the Console view. If you're running it form the command line, you should be able to enter your guesses right within the window after you run the command to start the program

Comment: Your code is working; I'm afraid your problem is a misunderstanding of how to run a java program. What are you doing to run it? What program are you opening on your computer, what are you clicking or typing that you think should run the program?

Comment: I got it running, but i don't quite get where i should put my guess
I am also in Eclipse, but i can't do anything in the Console view that makes me make a guess
And since i am all new to programming, i don't really know where i should write my guess in the command line (:

Comment: Does your console say "Guess a number between 0 and 1000"? Just click below that and enter your guess.

Comment: Aaah i figured it out! Thanks a lot!
I tried to run the program Again after i typed my guess, but yeah, didnt make a lot of sense (;
Didnt think of pressing 'enter' (:
Thanks a million for the help!